# Replicating Production to Test Environment w/ 2 servers in each

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I've got 4 servers total. The production side has live replication from **EARTH** to **TR**. The Dev side has live replication from **KOHOUTEC** to **CROMELIN**. I'd like to make a snapshot from EARTH to KOHOUTEC.

When I set this up, I get an error:

> Cannot drop the table 'dbo.SomeTable' because it is being used for replication.

Googling around, I found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326352.

That article uses this script:

```
sp_configure 'allow updates', 1
go
reconfigure with override
go
begin transaction
update sysobjects set replinfo = 0 where name = 'object_name'
commit transaction
go
sp_configure 'allow updates', 0
go
reconfigure with override
go
```

But is also has some pretty serious warnings:

> **IMPORTANT:** The 3724 message may occur legitimately when an object is marked for replication. Do not use the following workaround if the object is being used for replication.

And:

> **IMPORTANT:** Running sp_removedbreplication on a database removes all replication objects from the database. Therefore, all publications and subscriptions in the database are removed.

So I'm understandably a little nervous about doing this, especially since I'm not 100% sure what's going on in the first place.

At the end of the day, all I want is to have the development environment have a nightly copy of the production environment. If replication isn't the way to do it, I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!